# Remove the top and bottom padding in a SeekBar

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying make a simple music player. When I try to use the android's default seek bar in my music playback controls section, there is a default padding at the top and bottom of the seekbar. The effect I am trying to achieve is similar to the seekbar used in shuttle music player.

[image]

But this the effect I'm getting. I would be grateful if any would tell me how to achieve the desired result.I'm using linear layout as the root container.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because the option of specifying

```
android:background="@color/your_colour"
```

will not work because you have two colors there one for the Top and one for the Bottom.
**The working solution is by using a layerlist as follows:**
Go to your `drawable` folder create a file call it lets say
`back_ground_seek_bar.xml` and add the following code inside it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
          <size android:height="10dp" />
          <solid android:color="@colour/your_top_color" />
        </shape>
     </item>

    <item android:top="10dp">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
         <size android:height="10dp" />
         <solid android:color="@color/your_bottom_color" />
       </shape>
    </item>
  </layer-list>
```

Replace the colours with your own colors when you paste this.
Remember we have added top and height of as 10.But because we want our `SeekBar` to have colour then we have to set the height of seekbar to twice the value so It should be twice and thats 20dp. So we should add our new height of the seekbar to be 20dp as well set the background as the xml we have defined as follows. Go to your SeekBar and paste this:

```
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_ground_seek_bar"
```

For customization you can also change the values of `height` and whatsoever in the `drawable/back_ground_seek_bar.xml` but it should always be twice. The given height set in `SeekBar`aim is to divide it equally.

Comment: But the top and bottom space around the seekbar has different colors. In my case it's orange at the bottom and white at the top.

Comment: Let me check on a solution to that even in Java code. I will let you know. When I edit my answer

Comment: I have edited the solution @SnippyValson check the updated answer and see how it works.

Comment: I have posted your answer and you seems not to be online! Hope you will tell me how it works when you come back!

Comment: Yes I was on a trip. I will try it out and tell you how it goes. :)